# Why are discrete global grids vs. making a custom grid using a tesselation different in size and shape?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, equal-area, dggs

I need an equal area grid system that can vary in area (i.e. 100km2 to thousands). I have two ways of doing this at continental scales (Asia + Europe as an example).

One way is to create a tesselation using the sf package in R over a polygon that is projected using an equal area projection. This approach allows me to input custom area sizes.

The other way is to use pre-existing discrete global grid systems (like h3). This approach limits me to a limited number of options when it comes to grid areas.

[image: Plot showing different approaches will calculated areas]

But when I look at the resulting products I do see differences between them. The one using h3 has grids that vary in their shape moving north but the one based on tessellations is consistent throughout in shape and size. Both grids are reprojected to the same projection (equal earth). Why do they look different and is tesselation version technically not equal area?

Comment: That's because a H3 is a bit special, and it's grid is not aligned to longitude/latitude, see https://www.uber.com/en-PL/blog/visualizing-city-cores-with-h3/. To check the area just calculate the area for couple of grids around globe.

Comment: hi @GrzegorzSapijaszko , I added a new plot showing the areas of each of the bins and I noticed that the tessellation method is more consistent with its areas but my worry is that the tessellation (even done on an equal area projection) does not account for the spherical nature of the earth.

Comment: Yeah, it's all a matter of assumptions: is the planet spherical? Which geoid should be taken? What is the maximum allowable error? If your tessellation is for species distribution/mapping, then how big the grid should be? Is 12k km^2 enough? To much? Map is always a **representation** of reality. And saying direct and open: I would use `sf::st_make_grid()` if I had to choose.

Comment: Thanks for thoughts and advice!